# Why does MSI installer succeed when chosen component was not installed?

Tags: permissions, wix, windows-installer, acl

I have an MSI installer package that enforces the user to choose from a list of possible components to install, like "Version 2018" / "Version 2019" / "Version 2020". The chosen components will install themselves in a folder inside "ProgramData" that is usually writeable by every Administrator account on the system. However, in a recent customer support, this folder was created by the SYSTEM account. Probably the customer's IT installed the environment with SYSTEM privileges.

When the installer tries to put files into this folder it obviously fails. The problem is that the installer notices the missing permission, but still succeeds.

Is there any way to enforce MSI installer to abort / throw an error when a user-chosen component (or any other essential component) could not be installed?

Comment: I'm not sure that you've diagnosed this correctly. Can you reproduce the problem on a test system? If so, please show relevant logs.

Comment: We need a minimalist reproducible example and log files.

Answer (score 0):

What you want should be the default behavior of WiX / MSI as noted below. It's hard to say what's going on without a logfile.

Take a look at the WiX File@Vital attribute: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html

> If a file is vital, then installation cannot proceed unless the file
>   is successfully installed. The user will have no option to ignore an
>   error installing this file. If an error occurs, they can merely retry
>   to install the file or abort the installation. The default is "yes,"
>   unless the -sfdvital switch (candle.exe) or SuppressFileDefaultVital
>   property (.wixproj) is used.

It sets the underlying msidbFileAttributesVital bitmask in the Windows Installer File table as documented at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/file-table

> The file is vital for the accurate operation of the component to which
>   it belongs. If the installation of a file with the
>   msidbFileAttributesVital attribute fails, the installation stops and
>   is rolled back. In this case, the Installer displays a dialog box
>   without an Ignore button. If this attribute is not set, and the
>   installation of the file fails, the Installer displays a dialog box
>   with an Ignore button. In this case, the user can choose to ignore the
>   failure to install the file and continue.